# Android Layout and Views dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to display product colours like

[image: sample Image]

based on server response. While clicking the color the available size will show based on the color

Comment: add some code please

Comment: what have you done till now.

Comment: i don't have any idea. i have attached the sample image

Comment: i have just tried some ways. but i didn't get expected output

Comment: Try using horizontal recycler view it will help

Comment: @HarshPatel but when i click the color how to show the sizes based on clicked color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The Best solution is to use the `RecylcerView`
- You want the `LayoutManager` to be horizontal
- Below is an example :

  ```
  LinearLayoutManager layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.Horizontal, false)

  RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
  ```
- You will also create a class say `ProductAdapter` which will extend `RecyclerView.Adapter` which will hold the `Views` in the `RecylcerView`
- In the `ProductAdapter` you will specify the individual `RowView` that you want the `RecyclerView` to have
- Now you will set the adapter of the `RecyclerView` by creating the object of this adapter
- For example :

  ```
  ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter();
  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
  ```
- You `Adapter` will look somehting like this:

  ```
  public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
    private List<Product> productList;
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
      public ImageView productImage;
      public TextView color;

      public MyViewholder(View v){
          super(view);
          productImage = (ImageView) view.fincdViewById(R.id.product_image);
          color = (TextView) view.fincdViewById(R.id.product_color);
        }
    }
    public ProductAdapter(List<Product> productList){
        this.productList = productList;
    } 

    // Here below you will inflate the individual row view
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_view, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position){

       holder.productImage.setImageURI(productList.get(position).getUri());   
       holder.color.setText(productList.get(position).getColor())

    }

  }
  ```
- The variable `productList` will have the products whose image you want to display as a list
- You need to process the server response and put the response in the `productList` variable with some Network Library
- I would suggest you to use `Volley`

Comment: Thanks. But When click the color, The Sizes related to the color will show. previously i have get the sizes from the server

Comment: yes, sizes related related to color can be shown... Can you upvote my answer and mark it correct if it answers your question so that way other will know the right solution

Answer (score 0):

for color follow @Jai answer and for getting size use below code

create a Linearlayout with Orientation vertical in xml
then get your json Array Response for size.

```
JSONObject lJsonobjData ;
    JSONArray lJsonArrData ;
LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout); 

for (int i =0; i<lJsonArrData.length(); i++){
                lJsonobjData = lJsonArrData.getJSONObject(i);
String size=lJsonobjData.getString("size");
TextView tv;
tv = new TextView(this);
tvdata.setText(size);
}
```